# Como passar javascript de ".js" para HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho o seguinte código embutido no meu HTML:

```
<script>
// dec2hex :: Integer -> String
function dec2hex (dec) {
  return ('0' + dec.toString(16)).substr(-2)
}

// generateId :: Integer -> String
function generateId (len) {
  var arr = new Uint8Array((len || 40) / 2)
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(arr)
  return Array.from(arr, dec2hex).join('')
}   
document.write(generateId(20))
</script>
```

Tudo funciona bem mas gostava de ter todo o javascript junto num ficheiro ".js"

A minha dúvida é como passar para um ficheiro ".js" e devolver o resultado ao HTML?

Fiz o seguinte, criei um "teste.js" com:

```
// dec2hex :: Integer -> String
function dec2hex (dec) {
  return ('0' + dec.toString(16)).substr(-2)
}

// generateId :: Integer -> String
function generateId (len) {
  var arr = new Uint8Array((len || 40) / 2)
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(arr)
  return Array.from(arr, dec2hex).join('')
}
```

E no HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/teste.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Random String Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>generateId: id="generateId(20)"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Não funciona. Alguém pode ajudar este noob?

Comment: você quer colocar o teste.js, dentro de um diretório js?

Comment: Sim, Gabriel. Isso não será problema, vou fazer em produção quando entender como passar a string para o HTML. Obrigado!

Comment: se você quer colocar o arquivo teste.js dentro de um diretório tem que ficar assim no HTML <script src="js/teste.js"></script>

Comment: E como passar o resultado do javascript para a página do usuário?

Comment: eu fiz o teste aqui e está passando normal o resultado gerado

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vitoreis/g34r5cvp/

Comment: seu link não quer carregar e na segunda parte do JS, falta o retorno document.write(generateId(20));

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tem que mexer seu html, do jeito que você fez o resultado é apenas texto e você não está chamando a função.

Experimente realizar essa alteração através do próprio javascript ao invés de dentro do HTML.

Inclua um id para a sua tag `<p>`:

```
<p id="paragrafo"> </p>
```

Inclua a chamada da função via javascript.

```
<script>

    window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('paragrafo').innerHTML = "GeneratedId: id=" 
     +generateId(20);
}


</script>
```

Segue o fiddle com exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/guidi/kontvLsu/3/

Comment: Mas assim continuo a ter o javascript inline em vez de estar no ficheiro ".js", não é? Seria algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/foiovitor/nc4e86vx/

Comment: Não, eu coloquei inline apenas para fins de exemplo, as funções podem estar dentro do .js externo, aí você referencia o arquivo igual você já tinha feito e chama  a função normalmente.